# Which setting is responsible for making unmodified files not persist as tabs?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If you open a file in VSCode, like so:

[image: tabs]

Previous VSCode versions, if the file is unmodified, you can open a new file and the tab will be replaced with the new file opened. You needed to save the file to `persist the tab`. Now all files are opened as new tabs for me. Is there a setting that is responsible for this behavior?

Comment: search the settings for `preview`

Comment: I have `Workbench > Editor: Enable Preview` setting enabled as its description outlines behavior I want. Yet even with it, opening any new file will just add on more tabs. I think it's a bug perhaps.

Comment: what is this setting in your Workspace or your WorkspaceFolder

Comment: This is a setting for my User. Not sure what you mean with `workspace or your workspaceFolder`

Comment: Don't you have a Folder open or a Multi Root Workspace, they have there own settings

Comment: I have a project open. But the settings I am modifying are for `User`. And the workspace .vscode/ settings don't have anything inside. So that change should apply. 

With you outlining the setting, it seems to be this is a bug with VSCode so I opened an issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112817

Comment: How are you opening the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you are opening the files.  If you are clicking on them from the Explorer, then `Workbench > Editor: Enable Preview` will control whether those files open in preview or not.

If you are opening them from the QuickOpen panel, then see

> The `workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen` setting is now
> disabled by default, so that editors opened from Quick Open will no
> longer appear in preview mode.

- from the v1.52 Release notes.

So enable `workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen` so files opened from Quick Open do so in Preview Mode.